# sequilize.models shows an empty object even though all models are loaded in index.js file

Tags: node.js, next.js, sequelize.js

I have the following structure

```
database
 - models
 - config
```

The index.js file inside my models looks like below :-

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const db = {};

// let { DBconfig } = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.js')
import dbConfig from '../config/config'

console.log(dbConfig)

const config = dbConfig[env]

console.log('>>>>>>> ------- <<<<<<<<');
console.log('>>>>> config <<<<<');
console.log(config);
console.log('>>>>>>> ------- <<<<<<<<');

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

But when this file is imported and i try to access a singular model (eg. users) i get an undefined. I.E. i have the following code in my API file.

```
const models = require('../../../database/models')

const vendorToken = async function Cart(req, res) {

  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    const uuid4GeneratedToken = uuidv4()
    const { token } = req.body

    console.log('access_tokens')
    console.log('access_tokens>>>+++')
    console.log(models.sequelize.models)


    await RedisService.hmset('lala', screntid, token, 'none')
    await RedisService.hmget('lala', screntid)
    res.status(200).json({ myt_token: uuid4GeneratedToken })
  }
}
```

But when i console.log() the following i get `undefined` or `{}`

```
console.log(models.sequelize.models) // output --> {}
console.log(models.sequelize.models.users) // output --> undefiend
```

How do i load the modals correctly ?

Comment: Did you heck that `db` has keys right before `Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try checking using this line:

> console.log(db[your_database_name].models);

Or, check out this documentation [click here](https://morioh.com/p/54b361988798)